# outer join returns multiple copy of join columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pymssql

When I do an `outer join` on mssql, the columns I join on do not combine.

Here is my code:

```
select top 10 *  from customer_behaviour_1P2014  full outer join
customer_behaviour_2P2014 on customer_behaviour_1P2014.customer_identifier = customer_behaviour_2P2014.customer_identifier full outer join
customer_behaviour_3P2014 on customer_behaviour_2P2014.customer_identifier = customer_behaviour_3P2014.customer_identifier
```

This returns 3 columns labeled customer_identifier, instead of 1.

What am I doing wrong?

If it makes any difference I made customer identifier a index in each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting all columns from all 3 tables, and each table has a `customer_identifier` column (deduced from the `ON` clauses).

Each `customer_identifier` column in the result is from a different table. The values will be the same when matched or `NULL` when no row matches.

Specify an explicit column list instead of `*` to avoid repeating the values. Instead of the 3 separate `customer_identifier` columns, use a `COALESCE` function to return the first non-NULL value:

```
SELECT <other-columns>,
COALESCE(customer_behaviour_1P2014.customer_identifier, customer_behaviour_2P2014.customer_identifier, customer_behaviour_3P2014.customer_identifier) AS customer_identifier
FROM ...
```

Comment: so what's the way to select all columns and only select customer_identifier once?

Comment: @user1871528, I added that to my answer.